# Jquery $('img').load() event doesn't trigger when loadings images using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

High i'm making a images gallery where you can load images more via AJAX.

I have a `fadeIn` effect using the the following code.

```
$('img').load(function() {
       $(this).fadeIn();
 });
```

This work for the first set of images (which was loaded with the page) but when i call more via AJAX (See code below) the `$('img').load()` doesn't seem to tigger anymore.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
      $('.tile').fadeOut();
           $.post('http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{
                   'action' : 'da_ajax_posts',
                   'data'   : 'foobarid'
                 },(function($data){
                 $('#container').html($data);


  }));
```

This is the rest of my code:

```
<div id="container">
      <div class="tile w2 h2 t1 l1">
           <h2>Image10</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=385&amp;h=256&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/img10.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w1 h2 t1 l3">
           <h2>image9</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=190&amp;h=256&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w2 h1 t1 l4">
           <h2>Image8</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=385&amp;h=146&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Desert.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w2 h2 t2 l4">
           <h2>image7</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=385&amp;h=256&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Hydrangeas.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w1 h1 t3 l1">
           <h2>Image6</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=190&amp;h=146&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/img10.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w1 h1 t4 l1">
           <h2>image 5</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=190&amp;h=146&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Jellyfish.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w1 h2 t3 l2">
           <h2>Image4</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=190&amp;h=256&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Koala.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w1 h1 t3 l3">
           <h2>Image3</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=190&amp;h=146&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Lighthouse.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w1 h1 t4 l5">
           <h2>Image2</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=190&amp;h=146&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Tulips.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


        <div class="tile w2 h1 t4 l3">
           <h2>Image1</h2>
           <img src="/wp-content/themes/site/images/tim.php?w=385&amp;h=146&amp;src=http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Penguins.jpg">
           <p></p>
        </div>


</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When you do `$('img').load(function() {...})` jQuery takes all img elements it can find at that moment (in your case it is 99% document.ready event). Try `$('img').live('load', function() {})` to force jQuery search for img elements every time load event occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind this event again in ajax callback.

Write the following code after this line " $('#container').html($data);"

```
$('img').load(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: And `fadeIn` will be called twice for initial images. Great that it won't be noticed, though.

Comment: you can unbind the trigger function and then bind it again. like            $('img').unbind('load').load(function(){ // do stuff here});

Comment: `live` seems to be more elegant, admit it.

Comment: yes but it has its drawbacks as well. it may make the page heavy if there are large number of elements... Because it will do the same thing again again.

Comment: @AatifFarooq but your script also depends on the number of elements and is not protected from this drawback..

Comment: live will do this process every time the load is called. but i am doing this after an ajax call. So the frequency of binding and unbinding will be less than the live.

Comment: @madfriend also thanks to you because other script didn't work after the ajax load. which your .live() advised was usefull

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your load event with live:

```
$('img').live("load", function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: :(This doesn't seem to trigger for the original set of images.

Answer (score 1):

`live` is now deprecated, see `on` for a replacement : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Juste like `live`, its goal is to bind an event handler that will also be triggered for elements that didn't exist when you first bound it.

In a case similar to the OP's, what you want is :

```
// binding the event to the body but restricting its scope to img tags
$('body').on('load', 'img', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This couldn't work. Explained in jquery `on` documentation (linked above): "In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an <img> element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event."

Comment: As your answer was wrong and misleading four years ago, as it is now. Indexed by Google and confusing people (like me, searching for problem solution).